# Can pushkit Voip notification be use for an other purpose

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'd like to know if i can use pushkit voip notification, even if my application is not a voip application.(by it, i mean eventually publish it in the app store) I'm not trying to make any voip call, I'd just like to use it's functionnality to wake my application up even if the user has quit it, and process information from the background. I'm sorry if i'm unclear, english isn't my first language(i'll try and make it clearer if needed). Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Check it, I think you got a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48581495/ios-silent-push-should-update-application-badge-count/48581601#48581601

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you should not. Even if you do that, high chances (I would say 99.9%) that Apple will reject your app during App Review.

Pushkit is meant only for Voip Apps & Apple as far as I know is very strict while reviewing apps.

Comment: Your welcome. But let me tell you, as per my knowledge, this may not be possible. Once the user has force quit the app, notification can not be processed by app without user interaction. (except Pushkit).